# Why this code is not giving right result for large arrays?

Tags: c, arrays

First I am getting input for:

```
T \\ no of arrays 

n \\ size of array

a[i] \\ elements of array
```

Then I am giving the output for indices for which `a[i] = a[j]` and `i!=j`.

for example:

**Input:**

```
2   \\\ no arrays

3  \\ \ size of array 1

1 2 3 \\\ elements of array 1

3 \\\ size of array 2

1 1 2
```

**Output:**

```
0 \\\ as there is no same element

2 \\\ for (0,1) and (1,0) gets has same element "1"
```

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 10

1 ≤ n ≤ 100000 

1 ≤ a[i] ≤ 1000000
```

This is my code:

```
int main() {

    int t,T,n,i,j,count;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    for(t=0;t<T;t++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int a[n];
        count =0;
        int c[1000000] = { 0 };
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&a[i]);
            c[a[i]-1]++ ;
        }
        for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            if(c[i]>1)
            count+= c[i]*(c[i]-1);  
        }

        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code is not satisfying this [testcase](https://hr-testcases.s3.amazonaws.com/1932/input02.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAINGOTNJCTGAUP7NA&Expires=1410275095&Signature=OKeiX3fPAngnKCVs1vNKlUUVh4s%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) .

Comment: very bad looking format of question.

Comment: try using long long int for `count` variable

Comment: What exactly is the multiplication `c[i]*(c[i]-1)` supposed to accomplish? (For a simple testcase, try `1 3 1 1 1`, one array with three ones.)

Comment: After counting the no of times a variable in the array. We can calculate the no indices.
for 1 3 1 1 1 it gives output 6 for 6 possible indices

Comment: @molbdnilo doesm't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int t,T,n,i,j;
    long long int count,k;
    scanf("%d",&T);
    int *c = calloc(1000000,sizeof(int));      
    for(t=0;t<T;t++){
        scanf("%d",&n);
        int temp;
        count =0;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%d",&temp);
            c[temp-1]++ ;
        }

        for(i=0;i<1000000;i++){
            if(c[i]>1){
                k = c[i];
                count+= k*(k-1);
            }
            c[i] = 0;  
        }
        printf("%lld\n",count);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Changes :

- Used `calloc` to initialize the array to zero (don't know why, but your
  method of array initialisation gives segmentation fault)
- As the limit for `n` is `100000` hence the output may be as high as `n^2` i.e. `10000000000` which out of `int` range, hence used `long long int` for `count` variable.

Comment: Thanks but still it is not satisfying the testcase.

Comment: @MSati The code is working fine on my machine. Can you post the desired output.

Comment: 0
9948
9938
9999900000
0
9999900000
0
9980
9999900000
9999900000

Comment: this should be the output

Comment: @MSati: Isn't this the [`HackerRank: Sherlock and Pairs`](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sherlock-and-pairs) problem? This code passes all their test cases, I just submitted it to check.

Comment: @Blastfurnace oh my bad, I think I submitted previous answer of Nishant, yes the code is right

Comment: @Nishant can you tell me which compiler/software you use as I get difficulty in debugging the problem

Comment: @MSati I use gcc as the compiler, you can use gdb for debugging, Also compile using `gcc -Wall -g` command , it will show some additional warnings that are useful for debugging. Also I am assuming you are using an unix based OS